# enum java misplaced constructs error

Tags: java, enums

What's wrong with below enum declaration? I want to write a singleton enum, so declared `INSTANCE`.

I get errors - `"misplaced construct(s)"`

```
public enum demo {
  INSTANCE;
  WHITE(21), BLACK(22), RED(23), YELLOW(24), BLUE(25);

  private int code;

  private demo(int c) {
    code = c;
  }

  private demo() { }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get it compiling, just replace the `;` with `,`, as you haven't finished listing the constants.

Something like this:

```
INSTANCE,
WHITE(21), BLACK(22), RED(23), YELLOW(24), BLUE(25);
```

However, since you want to have a singleton, I suggest to get rid of the `INSTANCE` value, and introduce a `static` member that will hold the instance:

```
public static Demo INSTANCE = Demo.WHITE;
```

Comment: Thanks. Please explain how the last line works? why we are using only WHITE in the ctor?

Comment: Looks like i need to read about enums more, can you plz recommend any resource?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare two sets of instances within one `enum` class as you've done.

It isn't clear why you want an enum singleton of an enum, but if you want one `INSTANCE` to be a singleton, then you can declare a `static` variable to be one of the instances.

```
enum Demo {
    WHITE(21), BLACK(22), RED(23), YELLOW(24), BLUE(25);

    public static Demo INSTANCE = WHITE;

    // rest unchanged except for demo->Demo
}
```

It's possible to use the enum singleton pattern:

```
enum DemoSingleton
{
    INSTANCE(Demo.WHITE);

    private Demo myDemo;
    private DemoSingleton(Demo demo) { myDemo = demo; }
}
```

But that would be useless; you could just use `Demo.WHITE`.